# When to use Foo.Process(Bar) over Bar.Process() in OOP?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic

I don't know what these techniques are called, please help me rephrase the question if necessary.

I always face this dilemma when creating classes. Is there a rule in OOP or in some programming principles that encourages either `Foo.Process(Bar)` or `Bar.Process()`?

`Foo.Process(Bar)` and `Bar.Process()` does the same thing to `Bar`, the only difference is where the method is declared. The first  is property of `Foo` while the latter is property of `Bar`.

Comment: Both are valid operations. Just with this tiny fragment it's impossible to make any definitive statement one way or the other. Sometimes you want A, sometimes you want B.

Comment: @deceze when is that "sometimes"?

Answer (score 2):

That's a simple example.

```
Car c = new Car();
c.start(); //start the car

PetrolStationMan p = new PetrolStationMan();
p.reFill(c); //refill fuel tank
```

I hope you understand better that way.
Both are valid like @deceze said, it's just a logical question

Answer (score 2):

In OOP, state (data) and behaviour (functions/methods) are combined together, into objects.

Some methods tell you about the state of an object (getter methods). As those methods are tightly coupled with the object, they are declared as part of the class of the object. In the common case that the state is stored in otherwise inaccessible (`private`) fields, there is no other option.

Some methods alter the state of an object. If they are tightly coupled with the object, or they alter `private` fields, they must be declared as part of the class (as *mutator* methods) just like a getter.

A third, and significant case, is when you have polymorphism. That is, when the class of an object has more than one concrete types that have different behaviour. In that case which behaviour depends on the type (class) and thus *must* be declared as part of the class.

The remaining style, `Foo.Process(Bar)`, is suitable for cases where the operation is not tightly coupled with the object itself *and* for which there is no polymorphism.

```
 public abstract class Person
 {
    private String name;

    // This getter method access the private name field
    // so it must be declared as part of the class
    public final String getName() {
       return name;
    }

    // This mutator method access the private name field
    // so it must be declared as part of the class
    public final void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }

    // This method is polymorphic; Minion.getBoss() and Boss.getBoss()
    // have different behaviour and so must be declared as part of the class.
    public abstract Boss getBoss();

 }

 public class Minion extends Person
 {
    private Boss boss;

    public Boss getBoss()
    {
       return boss;
    }
 }


 public class Boss extends Person
 {
    public Boss getBoss()
    {
       // *I* am the boss, nobody is *my* boss.
       return null;
    }
 }
```